# Making sense of the addr2line message with C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, addr2line

I have been having this rare segfault, and while debugging it, I managed to get the following output from addr2line program.

```
void std::string::_S_copy_chars<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char 
const*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >
(char*, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char const*, 
std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char const*, std::vector<unsigned char, 
std::allocator<unsigned char> > >)
??:?
```

Since _S_copy_chars() is a private function in std::string, I am obviously not calling it directly. But I am unable to guess which public function is calling it. If I can figure out the public function, I can zero in on the null de-referencing that is causing the segfault.

I am suspecting the following code...

```
std::string CInProtocolBase::RetrieveStr(std::vector<unsigned 
char>::const_iterator& iter)
{
    unsigned long sizeOfStr;
    const unsigned char& size = *iter;
    memcpy(&sizeOfStr,&size,4);
    sizeOfStr = 
    boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::network_to_host_long(sizeOfStr);
    std::string str(iter+4,iter+4+sizeOfStr); // <= Could this be culprit??
    iter += (4 + sizeOfStr);
    return str;
}
```

The Other candidate is this:

```
std::string CInProtocolBase::VectorToStr(const std::vector<unsigned char>& vec)
{
    return std::string(vec.begin(),vec.end());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger, and look through the function call stack to find out where in your code it happens?

Comment: This is happening in production. I can't use a debugger there. The segfault message is the only hint I have. I am trying to figure what part of the code is causing this. The addr2line has pointed me to std::string::_S_copy_chars() function. I need to track down the code which is calling it.

Comment: And there's no core-dump you could use with a debug build? Because there's really no way of going up the call stack if you don't actually have a call stack.

Comment: Nope, I just have a segfault message. BTW, I updated the query with some extra info. I am suspecting one function that might do this. It is a 4 year old code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `memcpy(&sizeOfStr,&size,4)` I see two problems.

The first is that you copy four bytes from a one-byte variable. That is a clear [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The second is that `sizeOfStr` might be 8 bytes (on 64-bit systems GCC usually have `long` being 64 bits). This will let part of the variable be uninitialized and therefore be indeterminate, again leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Use normal assignment and let the compiler properly do the conversion for you:

```
sizeOfStr = size;
```

Comment: Can this cause the current segfault situation? How is it running for so many months on this production server before now? Shouldn't it affect from day one?

Comment: @Sharath It can indeed lead to crashes like the one you have. And the problem with undefined behavior is that it might *seem* to work for years and then one day something seemingly unrelated changed and it no longer works.

Comment: Thanks, let me make this change and then see if fixes the crash.

Comment: "sizeOfStr = size" doesn't work. memcpy is still required. But I changed unsigned long to unsigned int.

Comment: @Sharath What do you mean "doesn't work"? Even if you change `sizeOfStr` to `unsigned int` you still have *undefined behavior* since you copy four bytes from a one-byte source.

Comment: Please see my code, size is not a one-byte source, it is an unsigned char& to a vector<unsigned char>

Comment: @Sharath Ah, I see what you mean. But it's kind of wrong and totally misleading. You should have made `size` a *pointer* since that's how you use it. Also, now you don't handle [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which could be an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161020/discussion-between-sharath-and-some-programmer-dude).